# SELinux Permission Denied for a new framework service in android

Tags: android, selinux

I have added a new System Service into Android Framework in earlier versions (4.4) following this tutorial from [Texas Instruments](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/Android-Adding_SystemService)

But when I try to do a similar thing in Android Lollipop, the SELinux policy denies me to do so. 
This is the output from logcat.

```
05-11 15:49:51.362   248   248 I SystemServer: Test Service Starting
05-11 15:49:51.364   248   248 I TestManagerService: Started Test Manager Service
05-11 15:49:51.370    54    54 E SELinux : avc:  denied  { add } for service=TestManagerService scontext=u:r:system_server:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:default_android_service:s0 tclass=service_manager
05-11 15:49:51.371    54    54 E ServiceManager: add_service('TestManagerService',28) uid=1000 - PERMISSION DENIED
05-11 15:49:51.378   248   248 E SystemServer: Failure starting TestManagerService
05-11 15:49:51.378   248   248 E SystemServer: java.lang.SecurityException
05-11 15:49:51.378   248   248 E SystemServer:  at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
05-11 15:49:51.378   248   248 E SystemServer:  at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:496)
05-11 15:49:51.378   248   248 E SystemServer:  at android.os.ServiceManagerProxy.addService(ServiceManagerNative.java:150)
05-11 15:49:51.378   248   248 E SystemServer:  at android.os.ServiceManager.addService(ServiceManager.java:72)
05-11 15:49:51.378   248   248 E SystemServer:  at com.android.server.SystemServer.startOtherServices(SystemServer.java:551)
05-11 15:49:51.378   248   248 E SystemServer:  at com.android.server.SystemServer.run(SystemServer.java:257)
05-11 15:49:51.378   248   248 E SystemServer:  at com.android.server.SystemServer.main(SystemServer.java:171)
05-11 15:49:51.378   248   248 E SystemServer:  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
05-11 15:49:51.378   248   248 E SystemServer:  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:723)
05-11 15:49:51.378   248   248 E SystemServer:  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:613)
```

I do not want to disable SELinux policy. I just want the policy to allow my new service too. What should I do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check this link: http://androidosp.blogspot.com.tr/2014/11/selinux-seandroid-exceptions-for-system.html

You can simply goto: /external/sepolicy/service_contexts

and add your new service there. Thats it!

Comment: You should never modify external/sepolicy. SE Linux can be appended to at build time by modifying the BOARD_SEPOLICY_DIRS += some/path/to/directory.

For an example, check out the fugu AOSP device:
https://android.googlesource.com/device/asus/fugu/+/ad8b4d343204a7ada7bae0a44038af2a69d9d45a/BoardConfig.mk

Answer (score 4):

To file:

> android-dev\external\sepolicy\service.te

Add:

> type mytest_service, system_api_service, system_server_service,
>   service_manager_type;

To file:

> android-dev\external\sepolicy\service_contexts

Add:

> mytestservice  u:object_r:mytest_service:s0

where `mytestservice` your name service

It's help me

Comment: You should be setting a device directory in BoardConfig.mk not modifying external/sepolicy or on newer Android source trees, system/sepolicy.

Answer (score 3):

In Android 7.1.1 the service_contexts file has moved to system/sepolicy

to add A service "foo" to the policy add to the file service_contexts

> foo  u:object_r:foo_service:s0

And in service.te add:

> type foo_service, app_api_service, system_server_service, service_manager_type;

A device specific policy can be created by adding a service_contexts & service.te file in the devices sepolicy directory: device/myDevice/versionName/sepolicy

Answer (score -2):

add in your sepolicy file

- allow system_server default_android_service:service_manager add

Comment: No you can't do that. domain.te has this neverallow rule: neverallow * default_android_service:service_manager add;

so it will prevent compiling, if you comment out that neverallow rule, you'll fail CTS.